# strange error, returned value type different from the one in function body

Tags: ios, swift

I have XlsxReaderWritter Framework added to my app. I am having trouble with the first steps of using this framework, which is getting a worksheet in an excel file

Here is my code:

```
let file = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(syllabusFileURL.relativePath)! 
inputFile = file.workbook.worksheets[0] //this line does not compile and gives me this "Type [Any]! has no subscript members"
```

Alright so I cast it as the following:

```
inputFile = file.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
```

Now it compiles but I get a runtime error saying:

```
Could not cast value of type 'BRAWorksheet' (0x10df5fdc0) to 'BRAWorksheet' (0x10ce8e430).
```

So it seems the value is already `BRAWorksheet` and does not need casting, but as I said it wont compile saying its of type `[Any]!`

In the official documentation, here is how they get a worksheet;

```
#####Swift

//First worksheet in the workbook
var firstWorksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0]

//Worksheet named "Foo"
var fooWorksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.createWorksheetNamed("Foo")
```

Since it is an imported framework, I checked the original Objective-C file for the function. It does not seem to return [Any]!. Here is the body:

```
- (NSArray *)worksheets {
    NSMutableArray *worksheets = @[].mutableCopy;

    for (BRASheet *sheet in _sheets) {
        BRAWorksheet *worksheet = [self.relationships relationshipWithId:sheet.identifier];
        worksheet.styles = _styles;
        worksheet.sharedStrings = _sharedStrings;
        worksheet.calcChain = _calcChain;
        [worksheets addObject:worksheet];
    }

    return worksheets.count ? worksheets : nil;
}
```

So can Anyone tell me what the duck is going on??!

Comment: Check your import libraries, maybe you have 2 libs contains the same type `BRAWorksheet`

Comment: How about splitting up the `inputFile` line into two? See what `workbooks` you have, along with what `worksheets`?

Comment: @wajeeh you are a godsend. That was the case actually. I had imported both the XlsxReaderWriter as project and via cocoa pods. I removed the xcodeproj and now I can cast it. It still returns [Any]! though

Comment: @tdm3732 So it's solved now?

Comment: almost @wajeeh. it still returns a different value than its supposed to be, but the cast is working now

Comment: @wajeeh, its not actually solved.. Now the casting is really getting my way.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using swift 3

```
let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo", ofType: "xlsx")!
let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
let sheet: BRASheet = spreadsheet.workbook.sheets[0] as! BRASheet
print(sheet.name) // print "Sheet1"
```

Comment: The problem is I do not want to cast. If I cast, I can not save changes to the original worksheet

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of the optional result:

```
var firstWorksheet: BRAWorksheet? = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets?[0]
```